# are two random variables independent if their joint distribution can be written as the product of their univariate functions?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I know that, for random variables $X$ and $Y$, if $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is their joint distribution function, then if $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = F_X(x)F_Y(y)$, then $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

But what if I am just given that $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = G(x)H(y)$, where $G$ and $H$ are arbitrary univariate functions of $x$ and $y$? In this case, is $X$ and $Y$ still independent from each other? If yes, why is this? and if no, what is the counter example?

Thank you,

Comment: so in general, is it true that what I am wondering about does not hold?

Comment: what would be the counter example for this?

Comment: how can X and Y be independent in general? this is unintuitive for me because G(x) and H(y) are not neccessarily equal to the marginal distribution of X and Y... could you be more specific? I am confused...

Comment: I mean if we are already given that X and Y are independent, then we know that $F_{X,Y}(x,y)$ can be written as the product $G(x)H(y)$. However we are not given that X and Y are independent. We are just given that $F_{X,Y}(x,y) = G(x)H(y)$ for some univariate functions $G$ and $H$, and we have to tell whether $X$ and $Y$ are independent in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marginal of $X$ is $F_X=\int_{-\infty}^\infty Fdy=G\int_{-\infty}^\infty H~dy$.

The marginal of $Y$ is $F_Y=\int_{-\infty}^\infty Fdx=H\int_{-\infty}^\infty G~dx$.

Now$$\begin{align*}F_XF_Y&=GH\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty G~dx\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty H~dy\right)\\&=GH\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty GH~dx~dy\right)\\&=GH\int\int F~dx~dy\\&=GH\\&=F\end{align*}$$since $F$ is a PDF and integrates to $1$.

Note that $F_X(x)=kG(x)$ and $F_Y=\frac1kH(y)$ where $k=\int_{-\infty}^\infty H~dy$ and $\frac1k=\int_{-\infty}^\infty G~dx$. You can extend this to discrete distributions.

Comment: are you sure that $(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}Gdx)(\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}Hdy) = \int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}GHdxdy$?

Comment: Yes.$$\int\int GH~dx~dy=\int H\int G~dx~dy$$since $H$ is a function of only $y$. Since integral of $G$ between **constant bounds** is independent of $y$ (constant), we get$$\left(\int G~dx\right)\int H~dy$$